# Не выводит имя автора записи WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Не выводит имя автора на странице с постами. Просто пустота - null ,одним словом. Делаю сайт на openserver, может от этого не выводит?

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="blog-post">
                            <?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
                            } else {
                                echo '<img scr="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/blog/blog-1.jpg"/>';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="mt-4 mb-3 d-flex">
                                <div class="post-author mr-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>

                                    <span class="h6 text-uppercase">
                                        <?php
                                        if (the_author() == null) {
                                            echo 'Ильдар Мустафин';
                                        } else {
                                            echo the_author();
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="post-info">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar-check"></i>
                                    <span><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="h4 "><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            <p class="mt-3"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more">Читать статью <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто забыл вставить в начало блока с постами

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите 'echo'. Пишите просто: the_author(); (данная функция содержит внутри себя 'echo'). Либо воспользуйтесь фунцкцией get_the_author() если очень любите использовать 'echo':